# Does Windows 7 RC upgrade seamlessly for Vista Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I have Vista Ultimate x64 and am thinking of upgrading to the Windows 7 RC. I would like to know that others have perform this upgrade with success before trying it on my own development machine.

My devices are all standard components such as Western Digital/Seagate drives, Gigabyte motherboard and Intel Core 2 Quad processer.

Comment: Won't the answer to this always be YMMV?

Comment: @Alex yes - the experience will always depend on what third party applications and drivers are installed. On the whole though, Microsoft has really done a good job this time around.

Answer (score 2):

It works but Your Mileage May Vary (YMMV).

Answer (score 1):

I just finished an upgrade from Vista Ultimate 64 to the RC Ultimate 64 and it went very smoothly.  I actually tried to do a clean install first, but had an issue with my CD Drivers not being recognized.  I was running the Beta, so I did the Transfer your files to save my documents and settings.  The backup was about 45GB, and when it was done I installed Vista 64 clean, then upgraded it to the RC.  Everything worked really well, and the re-import of my data was very smooth as well.

Very pleased with the software - it's looking good.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to upgrade my laptop which had been running (and importantly in my opinion, shipped with) Vista Enterprise to Windows 7 Ultimate Beta and it did great.

Just recently I used the cversion.ini workaround to upgrade the same laptop from Beta to RC1 and that also seemed to work fine, though it felt like it took a long time.

Edit: (It's been a while, I'd forgotten until after submitting the answer) - the Beta upgrade had me remove Powershell 1.0. Also, the Beta->RC upgrade refused to run until I removed a bunch of laptop-vendor-specific TPM/security stuff. So don't be surprised if it asks you to remove software before upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.                .